# Перенос SVG файлов из HTML в CSS

Tags: css, svg, background

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите пожалуйста как перенести написание SVG фаила из html в background css ?

```css
.heart{
                 position: absolute;
                 top: 0;
                 bottom: 0;
                 left: 0;
                 right: 0;
                 height: $heartSide;
                 width: $heartSide;
                 display: block;
                 background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background:"new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve"><path fill:#A41E21; d="M186.1,27.9c-3-2.8-17.6-14.9-44.9-10.4c-22.8,5.9-40.4,25.3-40.4,25.3s-0.8,0.7-0.8,0.7c0,0-0.8-0.7-0.8-0.7
                    S81.6,23.4,58.8,17.5C31.5,13,16.9,25.1,13.9,27.9c-39.3,36,14.7,138.9,82.9,155.1c0,0.1,3.2,0.5,3.2,0.5c0.1,0,3.2-0.4,3.2-0.5
                  C171.4,166.7,225.4,63.9,186.1,27.9z"/></svg>') 0 0 no-repeat;
                  z-index: 1; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="heart">

<!-- 

<svg version="1.1" id="heart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
  .st0{fill:#A41E21;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M186.1,27.9c-3-2.8-17.6-14.9-44.9-10.4c-22.8,5.9-40.4,25.3-40.4,25.3s-0.8,0.7-0.8,0.7c0,0-0.8-0.7-0.8-0.7
  S81.6,23.4,58.8,17.5C31.5,13,16.9,25.1,13.9,27.9c-39.3,36,14.7,138.9,82.9,155.1c0,0.1,3.2,0.5,3.2,0.5c0.1,0,3.2-0.4,3.2-0.5
  C171.4,166.7,225.4,63.9,186.1,27.9z"/>
</svg>

-->
 
</div>
```

Не могу понять где я допускаю ошибку. Если разкомитить в html всё отображается как надо, а вот в css нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Убрать переносы внутри свг.
2. `fill` перенести внутрь атрибута `style`.
3. `enable-background` убрать вовсе.

```css
.heart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve"><path style="fill:#A41E21" d="M186.1,27.9c-3-2.8-17.6-14.9-44.9-10.4c-22.8,5.9-40.4,25.3-40.4,25.3s-0.8,0.7-0.8,0.7c0,0-0.8-0.7-0.8-0.7 S81.6,23.4,58.8,17.5C31.5,13,16.9,25.1,13.9,27.9c-39.3,36,14.7,138.9,82.9,155.1c0,0.1,3.2,0.5,3.2,0.5c0.1,0,3.2-0.4,3.2-0.5 C171.4,166.7,225.4,63.9,186.1,27.9z"/></svg>');
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

не советую делать так. лучше сохраните вашу картинку в отдельный `.svg` файл, а далее разместите его как обычный `img`. Вы также сможете менять и свойство `.svg` файла с помощью `CSS`, если он будет в отдельном файле.

Если же вы все же хотите добавить его в CSS файл, то вот вам способ:
Переведите ваш файл в [base64](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php) и вставляйте полученный код вот в так:

```
.КАРТИНКА {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,[полученный_конвертированный_код]");
}
```

Comment: Почему "не советуете так содержать"? И Всё таки как его свернуть в background ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 как его развернуть в background стоит в моем сообщении. А не советую, потому-что это довольно жирный кусок кода, который будет мешать в будущем. Лучше всегда все ложить по разным файлам, если это возможно.

Comment: Я имел ввиду как всё таки этот SVG код держать в background ? Я знаю что это реально https://jsfiddle.net/BlackStar1991/03a2zaqh/1/ В такой записе он тоже читаем + его можно заанимировать. Не могу понять что не так с моим кодом

Comment: @BlackStar1991 кроме выше-предоставленного метода - никак. Вы ведь понимаете, что вы пытаетесь вставить в `CSS` как у вас, код `HTML`. Как он у вас заработает?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mkLasfsq/5/ Как не странно заработал. Добрые люди подсказали смотреть на кодировку отступов

Comment: @Insider, *Лучше всегда все ложить по разным файлам, если это возможно* – это утверждение верно только для исходников. Да, в исходных файлах должен быть строгий порядок. Однако люди уже давно используют сборщики проектов, которые объединяют всё, что вам нужно объединить. `<img>` следует использовать исключительно для контента, но не для оформления. CSS-файл будет кэшироваться, поэтому наиболее правильным решением будет закатать в него в виде base64 этот самый SVG-файл.

Comment: @terron  про base64  написано)

Comment: Base64 для текстовых данных не нужен.